# access cpanel with server ip

Tags: cpanel, server

I bought a new hosting and got moved to a new hosting site. Now I can not backup the old server to connect to the IP. My host was CPanel

IP address: 72.52.124.50
            72.52.124.51
SSH port: 1887

testing this address but not work

```
72.52.124.50:2082
72.52.124.50:2083
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess 72.52.124.50 is your old host IP. If yes, these IP's are not responding to ping or ssh. Your old host may have stopped hosting service. Try to contact them.